# iPhone IOS device testing on Newer iOS than SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, provisioning

When doing preliminary research, minimum requirements for IOS development were limited to an Intel Based Mac, with Snow Leopard.  Since then, I have purchased my new (old) Mac, installed the SDK (4.3), and wrote my first App. Unfortunately, the highest SDK that this Mac will run is for iOS 4.3.  My iPhone that I want to test with is iOS 5.x.  I cannot figure out how to set up the provisioning to allow me to install my App on my iPhone.  I have paid my fee, went through the brief (aimed at a later SDK) helper, but my XCode wants me to install an older iOS on my phone to connect.  Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks in advance,

Sagan

Comment: I would try the official apple way first, but Jailbreaking is also option if that dosent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ad hoc build, and load the resulting .ipa file onto the device either via iTunes or a url.  Ad hoc builds will allow you to create a built copy of your app in a single packaged file which may be loaded on your device.

There's a ton of references around the web for how to do this, here's one guide for XCode 4:

http://benscheirman.com/2011/06/creating-proper-ipa-files-in-xcode-4

Here's a guide for XCode 3:
http://www.springtiger.co.uk/2010/12/06/creating-a-ipa-file-for-your-application/

Comment: Thank you.  Google, here I come.

Comment: Thanks... Every reference I find is for xCode 4.x ... I really need help with xCode 3.x.  If I had 4, then this wouldn't be an issue, because it would support iOS 5.  Still Googling, so if I find it, I will definitely mark this answer as correct (and post found link).  Thanks again.